# How to search a multidimensional character array swift

Tags: swift, search, multidimensional-array

I am looking for characters in a multidimensional character array. I created my own class of characters which contain the character and a found flag. I am trying to search the array for all the characters contained in a string. For some reason if the string and array contain more than one of the same character my algorithm just gets the last character and then doesn't find any other characters. It should find the first and then if there is another character that is the same it should disregard that one that was found and look in the array to find another. Can someone please help.

```
class myChar : NSObject {
var value: Character?
var found: Bool?
var row: Int?
var column: Int?
}

class myCharForArray : NSObject {
    var value: Character?
    var found: Bool?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var multiDimCharArray = [[myCharForArray]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    multiDimCharArray = createMainArray(nSize: 5)
    searchLinearName(userName: "AANDREW", arrayForTesting: multiDimCharArray)
    flattenArray(userName: "AANDREW", nestedArray: multiDimCharArray)

   }

func createCharacterForArrayMainArray(randomNSize: Int) -> [myCharForArray]{
    let alphabet: [Character] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    var randomLetterArray = [myCharForArray]()
    for i in 0..<randomNSize{
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(26))
        let randomLetter = myCharForArray()
        randomLetter.value = alphabet[rand]
        randomLetter.found = false
        randomLetterArray.append(randomLetter)
    }
    //    print(randomLetterArray)
    return randomLetterArray
}

func createMainArray(nSize: Int) -> [[myCharForArray]] {
    var mainArray = [[myCharForArray]]()

    for i in 0..<nSize{
        mainArray.append(createCharacterForArrayMainArray(randomNSize: nSize))
    }

    if nSize <= 10{
        print("RANDOM MATRIX: \n")
        for i in mainArray{
            var charArray = [Character]()
            for j in i{
                charArray.append(j.value!)
            }
            print(charArray)
        }
        print("\n")
    }
    return mainArray
}

func stringToMyCharArray(stringToChange: String) -> [myChar]{
    let chars = Array(stringToChange)
    var myCharArray = [myChar]()
    for char in chars{
        let thisChar = myChar()
        thisChar.value = char
        thisChar.found = false
        thisChar.row = 0
        thisChar.column = 0
        myCharArray.append(thisChar)
    }
    return myCharArray
}

func searchLinearName(userName: String, arrayForTesting: [[myCharForArray]]){
    let chars = stringToMyCharArray(stringToChange: userName)
    print("Linear Search")
    for char in chars{
        var i = 0;
        for arrayChar in arrayForTesting{
            i = i + 1
            var j = 0;
            for singleCharInArray in arrayChar{
                j = j + 1
                if char.value == singleCharInArray.value && singleCharInArray.found == false{
                    char.found = true
                    char.row = i
                    char.column = j
                    singleCharInArray.found = true
                    //  print("\(char.value!): [\(char.row!),\(char.column!)]")
                }else if char.value == singleCharInArray.value && singleCharInArray.found == true{
                    print("This Char \(singleCharInArray.value!) has been found [\(i - 1),\(j - 1)]")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for char in chars{
        print("\(char.value!): [\(char.row! - 1),\(char.column! - 1)]")
    }

    print("\n")
}
```

My output looks like this

```
RANDOM MATRIX: 

["A", "A", "W", "M", "S"]
["C", "C", "Y", "S", "K"]
["B", "M", "N", "P", "R"]
["D", "D", "B", "N", "V"]
["I", "Q", "K", "X", "C"]


Linear Search
This Char A has been found [0,0]
This Char A has been found [0,1]
A: [0,1]
A: [-1,-1]
N: [3,3]
D: [3,1]
R: [2,4]
E: [-1,-1]
W: [0,2]
```

it should be like this

```
    A: [0,0]
    A: [0,1]
    N: [3,3]
    D: [3,1]
    R: [2,4]
    E: [-1,-1]
    W: [0,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a new iteration on the next character as soon as you find one, so you need two `break`.

```
func searchLinearName(userName: String, arrayForTesting: [[myCharForArray]]) {
    let chars = stringToMyCharArray(stringToChange: userName)
    print("Linear Search")
    for char in chars {
        var i = 0
        for arrayChar in arrayForTesting {
            i += 1
            var j = 0
            for singleCharInArray in arrayChar {
                j += 1
                if char.value == singleCharInArray.value && singleCharInArray.found == false {
                    char.found = true
                    char.row = i
                    char.column = j
                    singleCharInArray.found = true
                    break
                //  print("\(char.value!): [\(char.row!),\(char.column!)]")
                } else if char.value == singleCharInArray.value && singleCharInArray.found == true {
                    print("This Char \(singleCharInArray.value!) has been found [\(i - 1),\(j - 1)]")
                }
            }
            if char.found! {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    for char in chars{
        print("\(char.value!): [\(char.row! - 1),\(char.column! - 1)]")
    }

    print("\n")
}
```